# JavaScript doesn't have to be inside a <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

The following code seems to execute JavaScript when the page finishes loading.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test page</title>
</head>
<body onload="alert('The page has finished loading');">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought that all JavaScript code has to be encapsulated in between `<script>` and `</script>`. So why was that not the case here?

Answer (score 4):

This is an [inline event handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Inline_model), which contains Javascript code.
They're generally frowned upon.

Note that Javascript can also appear in `javascript:` URIs (such as bookmarklets).

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript can be included in a page via:

- A script element referencing an external file
- Inline in a script element
- An [intrinsic event attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) (as in your example)
- Anywhere that accepts a URI and doesn't block JS URIs for security reasons (once upon a time `<img src="javascript:someScriptHere()">` worked, `<a href="javascript:someScriptHere()">` still does)
- Various proprietary extensions to CSS (such as [`expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Generally speaking, only the first of those techniques is a recommended method. Avoid the others.

Comment: Which one of these is my example?

Comment: @z-buffer — The one marked "as in your example": intrinsic event attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Not all JavaScript needs to be encapsulated so. This is part of the reason simply stripping out tags to remove XSS is not enough.

- [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html)
- [Avoiding XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 1):

This called "inline JavaScript"! Like inline CSS, inline JavaScript also is not a good practice.

- One of the reasons why we shouldn't use inline event handlers is that it requires us to mix JavaScript code in with our HTML/XHTML code.
- Other reasons are that it means cluttering up the HTML code with vast numbers of event handlers, whereas with scripting we can apply event handlers to any parts of the page, and even use a single event handler to handle events across multiple elements.
- HTML for the content, CSS for the presentation, and JavaScript for the behavior. By keeping a separation of behavior between these parts, we increase their ability to be maintained, and used across a wide range of situations.

This is not to say that inline event handlers are always a bad thing to do. Instead, realise that the use of them becomes a restriction on being able to more flexibly manage and maintain them. Take a look at following articles for more information regarding this concerns:

- http://css.dzone.com/news/why-inline-css-and-javascript-
- http://www.digital-web.com/articles/separating_behavior_and_structure_2/